# Search Function with Two String Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

Im trying to create a searchable database, where it takes in 5 ingredients from the user as a string vector, then compares it to recipes from a text file. The textfile is converted to a string, then broken up into tokens into a string vector. When I try to search the ingredients through the tokens, it outputs every single recipe, even if the searched item is not in the recipe.

I checked and the tokenize function works perfectly

I also want to make sure that the loop will check through an ingredient in EVERY recipe (not just stop once its seen one) any tips on how to do that?

I'm very new to C++, so I appreciate any help.

```
void recipesearch(const vector<string>& ingredientlist) //ifstream& recipes)
{

ifstream myrecipes;
string ingredient;
string file;
vector <string> tokens;
myrecipes.open("recipes.txt");
if (myrecipes.is_open())
{
    // read entire file into string
    myrecipes.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    file.reserve(myrecipes.tellg());
    myrecipes.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    file.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(myrecipes)),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    transform(file.begin(), file.end(), file.begin(), ::tolower);//makes database lowercase         
    Tokenize(file, tokens, "#");//places recipes as seperate strings into vector


    for (const string & ingredient : ingredientlist) // each ingredient in ingredient vector
    {
        for (const string & recipe : tokens){ //each recipe in recipe vector
            if (recipe.find(ingredient) != recipe.npos) // found ingredient in file
            {
                cout << "yo";
            }
        }
    }
    }
else cout << "Unable to open recipe file!";

myrecipes.close();

}
```

Comment: I find this code surprisingly nice for a beginner. Reserving, algorithms, iterators, foreachs ! Only the indentation is a bit lacking :p

Comment: Why not just read the file into a vector, and then search that vector?

Answer (score 0):

Given the problem statement, the design is insufficient. However, you mentioned being new to C++. If this is for academic purposes only, I would hold off on this type of problem and build up to it.

What you need to do is learn about serializing classes to files and back. The design of this problem would be much simpler if you were to have actual class representations of recipes and their ingredients, along with a means to read and write them to file.

Then it would just be a matter of searching through a collection of recipe objects via a predicate to a search function.

I would start here:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/serialization.html

Comment: [I see your link and raise you the updated one](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization).

Answer (score 0):

Flip the two for loops so you are searching in recipes for ingredients. When you find an ingredient, mark it as found and look for the next ingredient. Only when all ingredients are found do you "yo" for that recipe.

Here is a simple and stupid approach:

```
for (const string & recipe : tokens){ //each recipe in recipe vector
    for (const string & ingredient : ingredientlist) // each ingredient in ingredient vector
    {
        int ingredientsfound = 0; // keep a count of the number of ingredients found.
        if (recipe.find(ingredient) != recipe.npos) // found ingredient in recipe
        {
            ingredientsfound++; 
        }
    }
    if (ingredientsfound == ingredientlist.size())
    { // found all of the ingredients
        cout << "yo"; 
    }
}
```

A better approach was hinted at by Christopher Pisz in their answer: create a smarter recipe. Rather than a string, make a class containing the string. give the class a method to search for an ingredient.

```
class Recipe
{
public:
    bool requiresIngredients(const vector<string> & ingredients);
}
```

then you can

```
for (const Recipe & recipe : recipes){ //each recipe in recipe vector
    if (recipe.requiresIngredients(ingredientlist))
    {
        cout << "yo"
    }
}
```

And no one cares how Recipe does the search or stores its data. As you come up with better ways to store and search the other code around the recipe never needs to be changed.